# External Hard Disk Problem - doesn't mount / can't first aid / can't erase using disk utility

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, external-disk

I run MacOS Sierra 10.12.4 and struggling with my external 3.5 Data HDD not mounting after a short circuit in the Hard disk casing. I have purchased a new casing and have seen that the volume / partition still exists, but it is not mounting to the Mac. I had used Disk Drill data recovery and I can see that the partition exists and the data can be recovered.

The problem is:

1. I am unable to mount the HDD using disk utility as the mount is greyed out. I can see two volumes / partitions but the mount option inside each of them doesn't work.
2. I am unable to do First Aid on both the disk and the two partitions. The error is enclosed.
   [image: Error while doing first aid on first partition or volume]
   [image: Error while doing first aid on the whole external HDD]
3. I am not even able to erase the partitions or the disk. It gives the error shown on the screen - "Mediakit reports not enough space on device for requested operation."

Comment: Looks like a failing hard drive to me. You may have to get a new one. Were you using this hard drive for anything recently?

Comment: "short circuit in the casing"... that sounds expensive. Bin the drive & get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The following error appears if disk has GUID partition table and doesn't have *EFI system partition* (or it is less than 200 Mb):

```
Error: -5344: MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation
```

Even if you are not planning to use this external HDD for booting, Mac OS's Disk Utility requires this partition to exist.

You can create it with `gdisk` (GUID fdisk):

(First leave some unpartitioned space in start of the disk by moving partitions or backing up data)

```
Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1):
First sector (34-1953525133, default = 40) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:
Last sector (40-1172342001, default = 1172342001) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 512M
Current type is 'Apple HFS/HFS+'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = AF00): EF00
Changed type of partition to 'EFI System'
```

I created it with size of 512 Mb to be sure (200 is enough) and its hex code is `EF00`.

I'm not sure if it is required for Disk Utility, but it's better to format it with FAT32:

```
sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 <your partition device, i.e. /dev/disk1s1>
```

Additional information:

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/EFI_System_Partition Gentoo Wiki, includes information how to create it with gdisk
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition Arch Linux Wiki